# Im a beginner at programming and i believe Im wrong somewhere in this code as the result returned is NaN

Tags: javascript

```js
class person {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
  }
  calculateAge() {
    return new Date().getFullYear() - this.dateOfBirth.getFullYear()
  }

}

var P = new person("Mihai", "Popescu", new Date("03-08-2001"));

console.log(P.calculateAge());

if (P.calculateAge() > 80) {

  console.log("man, you're old you are:" + P.calculateAge() + " " + "years" + " " + "old!")
} else {
  console.log("man, you're so young you are:" + P.calculateAge() + " " + "years" + " " + "old!")
}
```

I followed a guide perfectly and he somehow got everything working and I didnt I got this:
NaN
man, you're so young you are:NaN years old!

I dont know why..

Comment: I copy-pasted your code without a single change. It works, doesn't give any `NaN`

Comment: Dates can only be parsed by JavaScript from a fairly strict set of syntax forms, and yours is not one of them apparently; it varies by environment (different browsers are different). Thus your birth date string is making an invalid date, and all the numeric values from the date will be `NaN`.

Comment: @VladDX it does not work in Firefox.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with date format. It might depend on your locale. In such a case, it has nothing to do with specific browser but your user/OS settings.

Comment: I'd suggest to use `Date.parse('2001-08-03')` instead

Comment: @VladDX `new Date(somestring)` does exactly the same thing as `Date.parse()`

Comment: @Pointy I used Firefox maybe thats why, Thank you! I didnt know browsers could affect the outcome of a code, im at the very beginning of coding

Comment: @VladDX I will use Date.parse() thank you!

Comment: I believe, you need to change `03-08-2001` to `2001-08-03`

Comment: @Pointy, they use the same mechanism but not "exactly" the same. `new Date(str)` returns Date object but `Date.parse(str)` returns amount of seconds.

Comment: @VladDX yea that's true, I meant that the parsing is (as far as I know) the same, because it would be kind-of weird if they were different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyze:

- First `NaN` is printed to the console by line `console.log(P.calculateAge());`.
- It means that `P.calculateAge()` returns `NaN`.
- Why it can return `NaN`? Because `new Date().getFullYear() - this.dateOfBirth.getFullYear()` results in `NaN`.
- Why `new Date().getFullYear() - this.dateOfBirth.getFullYear()` can return `NaN`? When arithmetic operation is not valid. The first operand is always a number. Then something wrong with the second operand.
- What can be wrong with `this.dateOfBirth.getFullYear()`? Probably something is wrong with the value of `this.dateOfBirth`.
- Where does value of `this.dateOfBirth` come from? It comes from value passed as an argument: `new Date("03-08-2001")`.
- What is wrong with `new Date("03-08-2001")`?

---

#### Assumption

My assumption is that `Date(str)` or its equivalent `Date.parse(str)` uses browser locale.

> I guess, author of the question is from Romania. Date format in Romania is `dd/mm/yyyy`.
>
> Therefore, when you pass `03-08-2001` as date value, it's failed to be parsed based on neither current locale (`dd/MM/YYYY`) nor ISO 8601 (`YYYY-MM-dd`).

Or maybe just Firefox can't parse a wrong date format.

#### Solution

Just use ISO 8601:

```js
new Date('2001-08-03')
```

> Useful links:
>
> - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#syntax
> - [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: This is an excellent answer!

Comment: Great job of leading the OP through the steps.  As valuable for its thought progress as for the answer.